# DRY - add certain number of elements to end of array until it's count reaches a specific int

Tags: php, arrays

Due to a fairly old library I'm working with, I need to chunk up arrays into even chunks of five. So, if my array has 9 elements, I need to chunk it up (5 and 4) and then I need to add a blank element to the last array to get it to 5.

I have written some very bad code that works, but I'm aware that is goes against DRY principles because it counts the number, and uses multiple `if` statements to push the correct number of blank elements to get back up to `5`.

Can anyone advise me how I should be breaking this code down so that `$chunkFive` is `array_push`ed to until it has 5 elements?

```
$blank = array("","","blank-image.png","",""); // create the blank image array
if(count($chunkFive) < 5){
    echo 'it contains less than five elements';
    if(count($chunkFive) == 4){
        echo 'insert one element'; // 4 present + array_push 1 = 5
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
    }else if(count($chunkFive) == 3){
        echo 'insert two elements'; // 3 present + array_push 2 = 5
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
    }else if(count($chunkFive) == 2){
        echo 'insert three elements'; // 2 present + array_push 3 = 5
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
    }else if(count($chunkFive) == 1){
        echo 'insert four elements';  // 1 present + array_push 4 = 5
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
    }
}else{
    echo 'it contains five elements'; // no need to adjust
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Trivial: `while(count($chunkFive)<5) array_push($chunkFive, $blank);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php):

```
array_pad($chunkFive, 5, $blank);
```

e.g.:

```
[20] boris> $blank = ''; // easier to read ;-)
// ''
[21] boris> array_pad(array("one"), 5, $blank);
// array(
//   0 => 'one',
//   1 => '',
//   2 => '',
//   3 => '',
//   4 => ''
// )
[22] boris>
```

The function exists since php 4 -- it normally pays off to use built in functions, as they are optimized c implementations in most cases.

Comment: I would never have thought to search for a native function, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
$blank = array("","","blank-image.png","",""); 
if(count($chunkFive) < 5){
    echo 'insert '.(5-count($chunkFive)).' element';
    while(count($chunkFive) < 5){
        array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
    }
} else{
    echo 'it contains five elements'; // no need to adjust
    // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
$fixedLength = 5;
$delta = $fixedLength - count($chunkFive);
for ($i = 0; $i < $delta; $i++) {
    array_push($chunkFive,$blank);
}
```

With this you won't even need the `if () {} else {}` part. If your array is of length 5 the loop won't be run, since `$delta` would be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all conditions:

```
$blank = array("","","blank-image.png","","");

for ($i = count($chunk5); $i < 5 ; $i++) {
    $chunk5[] = $blank;
}
```

I didn't use `array_push` because it does the same as a new array position and uses up a couple more php instructions (for func call)

Comment: Yes, but OP uses `$blank` to pad their array until it has five elements (all of type array)